# Compiler doesn't recognize non-nullable value if there is not an explicit null check

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, null

Example:

```
class Object(val value: Int?) {
   fun doesNotContainNull() = value != null
} 

Object obj = Object(randomValue)
```

Then when I use this object I can do a null check like this:

```
if (obj.value != null) {
  passNonNullableValue(obj.value) // compiles
}
```

Or like this

```
if (obj.doesNotContainNull()) {
  passNonNullableValue(obj.value) // does not compile
}
```

Why does the compiler complain about the second snipper? Can it not resolve that the value cannot be null? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The compiler doesn't look inside the function `doesNotContainNull` and so it doesn't know that the function is guaranteeing `obj.value` to not be null.

Comment: That can be annoying and reduces readability since you need to use obj.value!! even though you know the value cannot be null. Are there any workarounds? Or any plans this will be supported somehow in the future?

Comment: There is an experimental feature called Kotlin Contracts that solves your issue. You can find more about it here: https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/kotlin-contracts.md

Comment: @gpunto I tried it and it seems it's not possible to have it work as question described. You are limited to top level functions. but even with extension it's impossible to write a contract that will imply object fields are non null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR: Check out [this playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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).**

This is *sort-of* possible via Kotlin contracts - an experimental feature of Kotlin 1.3 to enhance support of smart cast.

Here is one simple example of `contract`:

```
@ExperimentalContracts
fun Object?.isNotNull(): Boolean {

    contract {
        // If I return "true", then it means that I am not null
        returns(true) implies (this@isNotNull != null)
    }

    return this != null
}

if (obj.isNotNull())
    print(obj.value) // smart-cast applied.
```

Now I say *sort-of* here because the usage of contract has some limitations. Only top-level functions support them. Which means that you would have to create an extension of the `Object` class. 
The other limitation is that we want to check nullability of `Object.value` here, not `Object` itself. This is not supported in contract definition. So even though it would seem ideal, the following does not compile:

```
@ExperimentalContracts
fun Object.doesNotContainNull(): Boolean {

    contract {

        // The following line gives an error:
        // Error in contract description: only references to parameters are allowed in contract description.
        returns(true) implies (this@doesNotContainNull.value != null)    }

    return value != null
}
```

As the error suggests, we can refer to parameters in the contract description. So we can come up with a workaround where we pass `value` as a parameter. In the end, the function will look like the following:

```
@ExperimentalContracts
fun Object.doesNotContainNull(value: Int?): Boolean {
    contract {
        returns(true) implies (value != null)
    }

    return value != null
}

if (obj.doesNotContainNull(obj.value)) {
    passNonNullableValue(obj.value) // smart cast applied!
}
```

Even though this approach works, it is dangerous because the caller may not always pass `obj.value` as an argument. So we would want to ensure that condition and throw a runtime error if the check fails.

```
@ExperimentalContracts
fun Object.doesNotContainNull(value: Int?): Boolean {
    contract {

        // "If I return true, then it means that $value is not null."
        returns(true) implies (value != null)
    }

    if(value != this.value)
        throw IllegalArgumentException("$value must be ${this.value}")

    return value != null
}
```

The complete example can be played with in [this playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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).

Comment: Issue with last approach is that it doesn't solve anything; if `obj.value` has to be passed to this function as argument, it might as well be used (and will be more readable) to check nullabiity on it directly.

Comment: I agree. It's not a complete solution because there isn't such support as of today. In a real life example, I would assume that the `doesNotContainNull` does more than just checking null. In that case, this approach may work.

Answer (score 0):

The *Kotlin* compiler does not know about the implications of calling `doesNotContainNull()`. To provide this information, [`kotlin.contracts`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.contracts/index.html) was introduced. Eventhough this API still has some shortcommings, you could abstract it away with a `sealed class` approach.

```
sealed class Object {
    abstract val value: Int?
    class NotNull(override val value: Int) : Object()
    object Null : Object() {
        override val value: Int? = null
    }

    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(value: Int?) = if (value == null)
            Object.Null else Object.NotNull(value)
    }
} 

fun Object.doesNotContainNull(): Boolean {
    contract {
        returns(true) implies (this@doesNotContainNull is Object.NotNull)
    }
    return value != null
}
```

It would be possible to use as if everything was implemented as you did. It's a little verbose though.

But eventually using `?.let` might be much clearer to read and understand.

```
obj.value?.let {
    passNonNullableValue(it)
}
```